# how do i add class to a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my on click function.

```
function toggleActiveClass(e){

    console.log(e);
}
```

here's where i call the function

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleActiveClass(this)" class="link--no-decor link--dark">
```

here's the output it returns in the console

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleActiveClass(this)" class="link--no-decor link--dark">
   <li>
      <div class="menu-item menu-item--google menu-item--radio">
         <span>...</span>
         <span class="va-middle">
         Personal info
         </span>
      </div>
   </li>
</a>
```

i want to add class "active" in the div tag inside that anchor tag like this.

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleActiveClass(this)" class="link--no-decor link--dark">
   <li>
      <div class="menu-item menu-item--google menu-item--radio active">
         <span>...</span>
         <span class="va-middle">
         Personal info
         </span>
      </div>
   </li>
</a>
```

tried using this

```
function toggleActiveClass(e){

    e.target.childNodes[1].addClass("active");
}
```

but it didn't work.
how do i add the class active to div? using javascript.

Comment: can you create JSFiddle or Plunkr for reference

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: just a guess, but should'nt it be `e.target.childNodes[0].childNodes[0]` ?
childNode[0] is <LI> and i'ts first childnode is <div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work because `addClass` is not a method of [DOM nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Node/DOM).

You need to change the class list:

```js
function toggleActiveClass(link)
{
  let div = link.querySelector('.menu-item');
  div.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.active
{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggleActiveClass(this)" class="link--no-decor link--dark">
   <li>
      <div class="menu-item menu-item--google menu-item--radio">
         <span>...</span>
         <span class="va-middle">
         Personal info
         </span>
      </div>
   </li>
</a>
```

> I have other div with active class i want to remove the active class from that div?

I'd have to know the rest of your document's structure, but at a guess:

```
function toggleActiveClass(link)
{
  let currentActive = document.querySelector('.menu-item .active');
  currentActive.classList.remove('active');
  let newActive = link.querySelector('.menu-item');
  newActive.classList.add('active');
}
```

Comment: thanks i have other div with active class i want to remove the active class from that div?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are passing `this` to the function which does not have `target`. To get the target property you have to pass `event`. Then `addClass()` is a jQuery method, to add class in vanilla JS, you should use `classList.add()`. Though you should use `toggle()` like the following way:

```js
function toggleActiveClass(el){
  //el.querySelector('div').classList.add("active");
  el.querySelector('div').classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggleActiveClass(this)" class="link--no-decor link--dark">
   <li>
      <div class="menu-item menu-item--google menu-item--radio">
         <span>...</span>
         <span class="va-middle">
         Personal info
         </span>
      </div>
   </li>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this pass event

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleActiveClass(event)" class="link--no-decor link--dark">
```

this will solve the issue